# representing anti-simmetric relations with directed graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Directed graph are used to represent relations.

I read somewhere that directed graph where arrows go only in one direction represent anti-simmetric relations. What justifies this kind of relation between directed graph and antisimmetric relations?

Comment: Are you asking why a directed graph can show a antisymmetric relation?

Answer (score 1):

If the arrows go only one way, then there cannot be a case of *distinct* nodes $a,b$ where both $a$ points to $b$ and $b$ points to $a$.

In an antisymetric relation, all elements that are related to and from each other are the same element.   That is $\forall a\,\forall b~((a\mathrel Rb \land b\mathrel R a)\to a=b)~$ which is:

$$\forall a\,\forall b\,(a\neq b\to\lnot (a\mathrel R b\land b\mathrel R a))$$

So the relation over the nodes of "arrow points to" is by definition antisymmetric when "all the arrows only go one way".